# Max aggregate function syntax (to be called by the supabase client)

Tags: rpc, supabase

I need to write a simple custom aggregate function that returns the max of a column (as MAX is [not suported by the supabase client](https://github.com/supabase/postgrest-js/issues/206)). Just not sure about the syntax, so any help is most welcome. I have tried permutations of:

```
  select max(my_column) from my_table as $$
  return $$ + 1
```

getting an error:
Failed to validate sql query: syntax error at or near "select"

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```sql
create or replace function max_value() returns int as $$
  select max(my_column) from my_table;
$$ language sql;
```

Then calling it through [rpc](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/rpc).